# Textbox inside ng-for only showing when there is data

Tags: angular

I am working on angular. I have some text boxes in the page and on clicking a button I am selecting data from database and showing it in the textbox.

The textbox is not visible until I show the data, I am new in angular please help

Code in ts:

```
addItems(value: any) {
    this.items = new IComboDetails(value.ItemID, value.ItemCode, value.ItemDescription, value.PackingtypeID, value.PackingtypeName, value.quantity);
    this.stockitems.push(this.items);   
}
```

My textbox code:

```
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

       <div *ngFor="let match of stockitems">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Code" required="" [(ngModel)]="match.ItemCode" value="{{match.ItemCode}}" />
       </div>
   </div>
```

button code :

```
<input type="button" value="Add Item" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addItems(newStockoutForm.value);newStockoutForm.reset()" />
```

I don't need the `ngFor` loop, I just return only one data, but I don't know how to load that.

Comment: You have `stockitems` in your Component Class while you're looping over `itemdetails`. There could be several other things that could be wrong. Could you please provide a minimal reproducible stackblitz sample to work with?

Comment: i believe @JM means is, unless he gets data from server "itemDetails" will be empty and thus in DOM textbox is not rendered, and it appears only when he gets the data. I guess, he wants to show empty boxes. @ JM , now since you may have varying no of items in your array and hence different no.of textboxes you cannot judge how many to render, unless actually received

Comment: @yanky_cranky yes I want to show empty textbox. there will be only one textbox get rendered

Comment: I don't need an ng-for loop, but I don't know how to load the one data without that

Comment: @JM you can pass a single blank object in `ngOnInit` ```const item = new IComboDetails("", "", "", "", "","");
    this.stockitems = [item]; ```

Comment: @SonuBamniya how to avoid ngFor and show empty textbox when no data

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!itemdetails || itemdetails.length == 0">
<label>Item Code</label> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="temporaryField"  /> 
</ng-container>

<div *ngIf="itemdetails && itemdetails.length > 0"> 

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails"> 
<label>Item Code</label> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemcode" name="itemcode" [value]="item.ItemCode" required /> 
</ng-container> 
</div>

<br/><br/>
<button (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
</div>
  `
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you have following requirements :

1) Only one textbox.

2) model value should be populated from server-end.

3) should show empty textbox in DOM, until model value received.

you can do the following to resolve:

1) Data-structure array is wrong for this scenario, since you will only have one value

```
 item={ItemCode:''}; // whatever fields in this object, empty on page-load
  addItems(value: any) {     
   this.item.ItemCode=value;   // map the corresponding value to the model
  }
```

2) No need to loop, simply map the model

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Code [(ngModel)]="item.ItemCode" value="{{item.ItemCode}}" />
  </div>
```

3) Populate model on click

```
<input type="button" value="Add Item" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addItems(newStockoutForm.value);newStockoutForm.reset()" />
```

Comment: @JM does this answer your question?